# Hide div in style - and show it in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to hide a div until document is ready - and then display it.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
<div id='initiallyhidden' style='visibility:hidden'>I am a secret - kinda!</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#initiallyhidden").show();
});

</script>
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Just a reminder that if the user has javascript disabled and css enabled they will never see this content.  If the user has javascript enabled and css disabled it will always be shown.  They're smallish use cases (especially css disabled) but still out there.

Comment: Good point, worth considering.

Comment: They're actually not that smallish: screen-readers (for visually impaired) and crawlers don't read css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `display: none;` css property instead. Also, I put your style separately =)

```
<div id="initiallyhidden" class="hidden">I am a secret - kinda!</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#initiallyhidden").show();
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .hidden { display: none; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your markup to:

```
<div id='initiallyhidden' style='display:none'>I am a secret - kinda!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use **display: none**  instead because it takes the element completely out of play, where as **visibility: hidden** keeps the element and its flow in place without visually representing its contents.

```
<div id='initiallyhidden' class='hide'>I am a secret - kinda!</div>

<style type="text/css">
  .hide { display: none; }
</style>
```